# A System.ArgumentNullException while delete (Action ) method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I created a delete method for table **Constante** whith a condition if the **NAME** field in the table **Constant** is contained in the **Formule** field in the table **Rubrique** this Name cannot be deleted: i have an System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null exception:with Source Error:

```
 Line 85:             {
 Line 86:                 IEnumerable lstRefData = GetListFromDatabase<VM>(dataType);
 Line 87:                 HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKey] = lstRefData;
 Line 88:             }
 Line 89:
```

this is my controller method:

```
public JsonResult Delete([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsRequest, ConstanteVM vm)
        {
            try
            {   
                List<RubriqueVM> lstRubrique = RefDataManager.GetRefData<RubriqueVM>();
                if ((lstRubrique.Any(r => r.FORMULE.Contains(vm.NOM))))
                {
                    ConstanteVM assur = ServiceApplicatif.Delete(vm.ConstanteId);

                    ViewData["ConstanteType"] = new SelectList(RefDataManager.GetRefData<ConstanteTypeVM>(), "ConstanteTypeCode", "ConstanteTypeLibelle");

                    DataCache dataCache = new DataCache(CurrentSecurityContext.TenantID);
                    dataCache.DropDataCache<ConstanteVM>();

                }

                return Json(new[] { vm }.ToDataSourceResult(dsRequest, ModelState));
            }

            catch
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("NOM", "Suppression impossible ");
                return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
            }
        }
```

Comment: There is an object which is null. if you could show the entire error.

Comment: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value /Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null./Parameter name: value
Source File: c:\Users\olfa\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\NeoSante\NeoPaie\NeoPaie.Web.MVC\Common\DataCache.cs    Line: 87

Comment: i didn't know what object is null exactly?and how tof fix it

Comment: Look at line 87 in your source file. Someone on that line is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know which object is `null`, simply put a breakpoint at the beginning of controller. And trace until you find nullable object or error raises. It's hard to say anything without that.